# Failed to save manifest. Error details: KeyValueMustBeNull

Tags: azure, certificate, manifest

I am trying to upload a new manifest for an application I have in the new Azure portal.  However, when I try to upload the manifest with the relevant certificate information I receive the following error:

```
Failed to save manifest. Error details: KeyValueMustBeNull
```

[image]

I have tried both editing in the web browser and downloading/uploading the modified manifest with same results.  I can set the key value to null and have it save but my application cannot authenticate with the base64 key value as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this is an error within the Azure portal itself.  I was able to to resolve with the following:

```
Symptom: O365 portal error “Failed to upload manifest    file. You
can make adjstments in the editor and save, or discard.  Error details: "KeyValueMustBeNull”

Root cause: Tried to upload    the same “KeyId” twice in a row. 
Solution: Just modify one    character in the keyId field in the
```